# isolate data from long string

Tags: python, string

Assume the following code sample

```
fullstring = """Diamond Ring
+50 to Strength 
+28% to Resistance
some extra text"""


if fullstring.find('% to Resistance') != -1:
    print("Found!")
    # isolate value to the left of %
    # store value
```

I want to extract the following value from my string

```
28
```

and store them

Comment: Using the `re` module, you would use `re.findall(r"[0-9]+", fullstring)`. It returns a list of all integers in the string.

Comment: i only want it to return 1 value though, the resistance value